# Pandas, how to group and count samples without loop?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to learn pandas by doing data analysis on Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2021 data. Data can be accessed from https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey. 
My goal is to retrive 5 most common languages used by every developer type.
In summary a sample's DevType looks like this:

```
 C++;HTML/CSS;JavaScript;Objective-C;PHP;Swift
```

LanguageHaveWorkedWith looks like this:

```
Developer, desktop or enterprise applications;Developer, full-stack;Developer, back-end
```

So every language and type is seperated by semicolon(;).

I achieved this by using loops. Here is the sample output I wanted:

```
...
Developer, back-end
JavaScript: 72.66%
SQL: 58.62%
HTML/CSS: 56.65%
C#: 46.8%
Python: 40.15%

Developer, front-end
JavaScript: 92.19%
HTML/CSS: 78.91%
SQL: 54.3%
TypeScript: 51.17%
Node.js: 50.39%
...
```

Code for this:

```
from collections import Counter
dev_type_info = {}
for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
    dev_types = row['dev_type'].split(';')
    for dev_type in dev_types:
        dev_type_info.setdefault(dev_type, {
            'total': 0,
            'language_counter': Counter()
        })
        languages = row['languages'].split(';')
        dev_type_info[dev_type]['language_counter'].update(languages)
        dev_type_info[dev_type]['total'] += 1


for dev_type, info in dev_type_info.items():
    print(dev_type)
    for language, value in info['language_counter'].most_common(5):
        language_pct = (value / info['total']) * 100
        language_pct = round(language_pct, 2)

        print(f'\t{language}: {language_pct}%')
```

Is there any way to achieve this using pandas or shorter implementation and not loops like above?

Comment: something like `df['dev_type'].str.split(';').explode().groupby(level=0).value_counts()`, or `df['dev_type'].str.get_dummies(';')`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.str.split` to convert your semi-colon separated column into a list, then [pd.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand them into separate rows. After that it's a matter of counting:

```
df['LanguageHaveWorkedWith'] = df['LanguageHaveWorkedWith'].str.split(";")
df['DevType'] = df['DevType'].str.split(";")

tab = df[['DevType','LanguageHaveWorkedWith']].\
explode(['DevType']).explode(['LanguageHaveWorkedWith']).\
value_counts().to_frame("counts")
```

Then get the percentages per `DevType` , note that in your example they don't sum up to 100%, while this will:

```
tab = tab.reset_index()
tab['perc'] = 100*tab['counts'] / tab.groupby('DevType')['counts'].transform('sum')
```

The top 5 per developer type:

```
    tab.groupby('DevType').head(5).sort_values('DevType')
 
                  DevType LanguageHaveWorkedWith  counts       perc
234   Academic researcher             Bash/Shell    1065   6.621076
229   Academic researcher                    C++    1114   6.925707
119   Academic researcher                 Python    2090  12.993472
198   Academic researcher             JavaScript    1287   8.001243
212   Academic researcher               HTML/CSS    1179   7.329810
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Couple of notes: I got error in the explode(['x']) so I changed both explode's to explode('x'). Also I could not describe what tab['perc'] provides us. Is it better to divide tab['counts'] with total people per developer type, or the total language counts used by per developer? What is the difference between these two?